# Looking for specific characters in the filename in a directory (powershell)

Tags: powershell, script, file-search

Trying to get a list of all USA Titles in the text file

this is what i have :

$Path = "f:\Test\

$Text = "(USA)"

$Results = "C:\Temp\test.txt"

clear

Get-ChildItem $Path | 
Where-Object {$_.Name -match $Text} |
Out-File $Results

the result is

-a----       12/13/2019   9:04 AM           6336 Activision Decathlon, The (USA).zip
-a----       12/13/2019   9:04 AM           3157 Adventure (USA).zip
-a----       12/13/2019   9:04 AM           3142 Adventures of TRON (USA).zip
-a----       12/13/2019   9:04 AM           2965 Air Raid (USA).zip
-a----       12/13/2019   9:04 AM           3283 Air Raiders (USA).zip
-a----       12/13/2019   9:04 AM           1884 Air-Sea Battle ~ Target Fun (Japan, USA).zip
-a----       12/13/2019   9:04 AM           2744 Airlock (USA) (Proto).zip
-a----       12/13/2019   9:04 AM           2727 Airlock (USA).zip
-a----       12/13/2019   9:04 AM           3476 Alien (USA).zip
-a----       12/13/2019   9:04 AM           2958 Alligator People (Europe, USA) (Proto).zip
-a----       12/13/2019   9:04 AM           3699 Alpha Beam (Japan, USA) (Beta) (1982-12-22).zip
-a----       12/13/2019   9:04 AM           5902 Alpha Beam with Ernie (Japan, USA).zip
-a----       12/13/2019   9:04 AM           2962 Amidar (USA).zip
-a----       12/13/2019   9:04 AM           4929 AndroMan on the Moon (USA) (Proto).zip

but when I open the text files as shown above i see some titles with (Japan, USA) (Europe, USA) i would like to omit those and others in the test.txt file

Comment: the `()` chars are used by  regex itself ... so you need to escape them to be able to use them in a regex pattern. the simplest way to do that is `[regex]::Escape($PatternToEscape)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can just escape the parenthesis, replace your:

```
$Text = "(USA)"
```

with:

```
$Text = "\(USA\)"
```